# How to flatten entity graph with date filter

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have two tables, Accounts and Results, that I wish to flatten for my dto. There's a one to many from Accounts as the Results table maintains historic data (for other use cases), but for this project (UWP app) I just want to add the latest row of Results into an expanded Account dto for the current situation. I don't quite get lazy loading yet, but as the Results table will grow to millions of rows, there has to be filtering done on the client side before the Results data is downloaded.

So far I've been using this view:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Accounts.AccountID, 
        Accounts.AccountName, 
        Results.ResultTime AS LastUpdated,
        Results.Balance, 
        Results.Equity, 
        Results.Margin,
        Results.Step, 
        Results.NextIncrease, 
        Results.NextLotSize,
        Results.Symbol,
        Results.Ask,
        Results.Bid, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by Results.AccountID ORDER BY Results.ResultTime DESC) AS RN 
    FROM dbo.Accounts INNER JOIN dbo.Results ON Accounts.AccountID = Results.AccountID
)
SELECT  AccountID, AccountName, LastUpdated, Balance, Equity, Margin, Step, NextIncrease, NextLotSize, Symbol, Ask, Bid
FROM cte WHERE RN = 1;
```

but it's getting painfully slow. Is there a "correct" way to fill DBSet(Account) first and then fill DBSet(Result) with only the last row for each Result based on Result.ResultTime DESC to make this more efficient?

TIA!
Dennis

Comment: Given that you've written your own SQL query, this seems to be more of a SQL issue rather than an EF issue. That being said, it is getting "slow" because you're using ROW_NUMBER() OVER which has to evaluate all results. Perhaps a sub-query would be better?

Comment: The SQL query was used for the initial mockup, but doesn't really have a place in the dbs. The created view is only relevant for the new app, which will need several changes to data structures, hence I'd rather do these transformations in LINQ. If I could only get a good enough understanding of lazy loading to actually do it... I'm considering grabbing a list of Account and then foreach loop through it to fill the Results part of the dto object, but I worry I'll end up with a mess of dbs connections while some simple and well know pattern is laughing at me just out of sight.